# cron job laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel-5, cron

I'm trying to set up a task every minutes. I put in the crontab as root :

```
* * * * usr/bin/php /var/www/html/projet1613/artisan schedule:run 1>> /dev/null 2>&1
```

I can see in the file cron.log that the command is run

```
Feb 22 13:33:01 serveur-auditpro-1613 CRON[5225]: (root) CMD (usr/bin/php /var/www/html/projet1613/artisan schedule:run 1>> /dev/null 2>&1)
Feb 22 13:33:02 serveur-auditpro-1613 CRON[5225]: (root) CMD (usr/bin/php /var/www/html/projet1613/artisan schedule:run 1>> /dev/null 2>&1)
```

In my laravel project in the Kernel.php, I put this :

```
$schedule->command(SaveResult::class)->cron('* * * * *');
```

When I make the order by myself everything is ok but when it is done every minute by the crontab nothing happens.

Do you have an idea?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit log of project :**

```
/bin/sh: 1: usr/bin/php: not found
```

I don't understand why because when I go in the directory usr/bin there is php.

Comment: What does your project logger say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm new to using the scheduling feature so i haven't really looked into it much but is there a reason to "run the task on a custom Cron schedule"? The reason i ask is cause i usually use

```
$schedule->command(SaveResult::class)->everyMinute();
```

Haven't had any issues doing it this way

EDIT: Based on your error log you are having issues calling php. If it is in your path, then you should update your cron to `* * * * php /var/www/html/projet1613/artisan schedule:run 1>> /dev/null 2>&1`

EDIT2: just noticed that the problem is likely due to you calling it `usr/bin/php` instead of `/usr/bin/php`

Comment: It's just for testing, if it's work. In real I will do it every 31th December.

Comment: that's telling you it can't find php at that path... how do you call the artisan command? `/user/bin/php artisan` or `php artisan` if php is already in your path then you need to update the cron to be `* * * * php /var/www/html/projet1613/artisan schedule:run 1>> /dev/null 2>&1`

Comment: I call it with 'php artisan'. Thanks it's works with only php. I don't know why with the path it didn't work

Comment: i think you just forgot the `/` so it wasn't getting the correct path. If this fixed the issue could you please mark as accepted @Erylis. Thanks